# Backspace doesn't delete inner html tags of a contenteditable DIV in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable

I have created a DIV with attribute `contenteditable=true` and appended children like `span` and `a` with attributes `contenteditable=false`.

Wanted to test if the entire node be deleted with a single backspace and to my surprise Firefox couldn't delete the elements.

Also, this works as expected in all major desktop browsers except Firefox. 
Any clues on this or what could be the possible workaround?

Found the exact issue on bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=439808).

Comment: [Bugzilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685452) (please vote to influence them to fix it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay! found the solution... its rather simple than what you would think. I am actually inserting html for links, so using `<a>` here. The `<a>` tag has attribute set to contenteditable=false and its not getting deleted with a backspace. So I have created an inner `<span>` level with contenteditable=true for firefox and that did the trick.

```
<div contentEditable="true">
   <a href="your/url/path" contentEditable="false">
     <span contentEditable="true">link here</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

This is required in Firefox only. Other browsers treat this as expected with the span having content contenteditable=false.

Comment: It still behaves kind of quirky but better than nothing :)

Answer (score 2):

I have faces the same terrible bug and had no choice but to make an elaborate javascript-based solution that listens to keypress events and if <kbd>backspace</kbd> was pressed, and the caret was just at the start offset of a text node, and the node before it is an element node, then delete that whole element node.

```js
// credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25397485/104380
var isFF = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i)
var editableElm = document.querySelector('div')

// listen to any key press
if( isFF )
  editableElm.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)

function onKeydown(e){
  if( e.key == "Backspace"  ){
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    
    // if caret is at the begining of the text node (0), remove previous element
    if( selection && selection.anchorOffset == 0 )
      selection.anchorNode.previousSibling.parentNode.removeChild(selection.anchorNode.previousSibling)
  }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable='true'>
  Try deleting theme <mark contenteditable='false'>marked</mark> words on <mark contenteditable='false'>Firefox</mark> ok?
</div>
```

Comment: This deletes elements before the div, not the content inside it.

Comment: @TylerLazenby This is what OP asked for. this whole question is about solving the FF bug where the last node cannot be delete, **not** the node's text content so you've said in your comment, and I Quote the OP: *...entire node be deleted with a single backspace*

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an "onkeydown" function on the editable div to stop event propagation (as follows). Worked for me:

`onKeyDown = (e) => { e.stopPropagation(); }`