# How to remove W3C-invalid styles

Tags: css

Is there list of styles that browsers use as their own interpretation of css.
By example IE10 puts a extra remove button in the input of a form and firefox adds a dotted line to links.

```
input::-ms-clear { //Remove IE10's “clear field” X button
  display: none;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner { //Removing The Dotted Outline FireFox
  border: 0; 
}
```

Considering I do not know which browsers ussing by different css I wonder if here is a list or a rest.css.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123063/what-does-moz-document-url-prefix-do)? This is, for example, for firefox.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When searching, look for _"vendor prefixes"_. Or, a search for _ms moz_ would have got you going.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor prefixes (Such as `-ms-`, `-moz-`, `-webkit-`, etc.) simply aren't valid code. Since they're not part of the W3C spec, they fail validation. They work in the browser(s) they're intended for, and fail without affecting other CSS properties in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks I did not know the term vendor prefixes. I am looking for a list of css vendor prefixes. But the term vendor prefixes will suffice

Comment: Could you elaborate on "list of css vendor prefixes?"