# fire alert on disabled button not working on firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an alert when you click on a disabled button and the following code works fine in Chrome, but it isn't firing the alert in Firefox.

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "disabled" && e.target.disabled){
        alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="disabled" type="button" value="clk" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: My bad..it indeed is working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y3cJ/ is what you looking for ?

Comment: @RakeshShetty this also not working in firefox

Comment: @codemania it is working in firefox too

Comment: @RakeshShetty I have firefox version 29...not working in this version

Comment: @codemania I have 28.0 see javascript is enable in firefox or not. To check see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967344

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53945/discussion-between-codemania-and-rakesh-shetty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : It is working in firefox version 28.0, here is the screenshot[image: screenshot]

```
<form>
<input id="disabled" type="button" value="clk" disabled>
</form>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){

  var isDisabled = $('#disabled').prop('disabled');

    if (isDisabled)
    {
            alert('yes');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('no');
    }    

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y3cJ/)

Also you cannot have a mouse event such as click on disable element. Alternative you can do like this : [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/yf2t4/)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields that are disabled. Any event that starts at the disabled form field is completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you click on the disabled button, the source of the event is the disabled button and the click event is completely wiped out. The browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked, nor does it pass the click event on. It's as if you are clicking on a black hole on the web page.

source: [Disabled button stealing onclick events in firefox](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?186057-Disabled-button-stealing-onclick-events-in-firefox)

I create this fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UBJb/) according @VDesign post refer to an older question.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
    <input id="disabled" type="button" value="clk" disabled>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("div > div").click(function (evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@AlexChar's answer perfectly captures the underlying problem: *Firefox swallows click events (and maybe others) on `disabled` input elements.* I'm adding this answer because I think there's a slightly less hacky way to address this issue in 2020. If you turn off `pointer-events` for disabled `input` elements (`input:disabled`) then the event will bubble up to parent `div`. This can be done only for Firefox via the [`@-moz-document url-prefix()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123063/what-does-moz-document-url-prefix-do) rule.

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  input:disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="alert('working!')">
  <input disabled>
</div>
```

Note that this does come with the downside of not being able to highlight and copy the text in the `disabled` input, but there are other ways around that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for this issue:

Review [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Placing a div around your disabled button and append an onclick event on the div will do the trick.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I know this is very old, but see the "doesn't propagate up the DOM tree" bit of @AlexChar's answer above. At least in the current version of FF, the event wouldn't bubble up to the `<div>`. In fact, this is exactly the issue I'm running into (the event is completely swallowed by Firefox).