# Restore default Firefox <select> styling with inline or scoped CSS

Tags: css, firefox, select

I'm working on a site with lots of (not so great) styling on the select element and I'd like to restore firefox defaults for one particular page.  It seems to be primarily the `background` and `border` styles which are breaking firefox's rendering.

The problem is:

a) I have no idea what the default browser style should be to make it look like it does when no styles are set.  When I look in the web inspector under browser styles it is a very long list of settings which would look like overkill just to override two stylesheet settings

b) I don't want to apply all the firefox specific browser styles and end up breaking styling on other browsers.

How do I get defaults back without messing everything up?

An acceptable answer can be either inline or scoped `<style>` element but the master stylesheet cannot be changed or omitted.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a quick demo illustrating the problem and the failed results of currently proposed answers.  There's also a jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkd3byud/2/

```css
select { margin: 10px 0; }
div select {
    border: 2px solid tomato;
}

.oriol {
    all: unset;
}

.boucher {
    background: initial;
    border: initial;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Option</option>
</select>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="oriol">
        <option>Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="boucher">
        <option>Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove any CSS pertaining to that element, that will allow all browsers to use the default styling.

Comment: The CSS is on a master stylesheet which is loaded on every page.  I don't want to edit the master since it would affect every page on the site.  I only want to revert the select elements **on this one page** to their default styling.

Comment: Then add a unqiue class to that page and in the master CSS use the [not](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector to exclude styling the element on that page.

Comment: @APAD1 - I specifically stated in my question "the master stylesheet cannot be changed".  While I appreciate your input, I'm looking for an answer that conforms to what I've outlined in the question.

Comment: I'm aware of what was stated in your question, however, the reasoning you gave for that statement is that you did not want to affect the styling of the select boxes on other pages, which my suggestion does not do. Now if you had said that you were looking for a solution that didn't involve changing the master stylesheet because you did not have access to it, that would be a different story. I am simply telling you what the easiest solution would be. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @APAD1 - for the record I also think this was made pretty clear in the title of the question itself.

Comment: ok, @APAD1 - I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve changing the master stylesheet because I do not have access to it.

Comment: Why not just add classes? I mean sure it's a little of a hassle.. but it makes sure you only affect the stuff that you wanna change....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only ways to prevent some styles from being applied are:

- Removing those styles from the stylesheet
- Overriding them with the desired styles

Since you don't want the first way, it must be the second.

CSS3 introduces the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) and [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) keywords, and the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) shorthand property. So, to unset some styles, you can use

```css
background: unset; /* Unset single property */
```

```css
all: unset; /* Unset all properties (but unicode-bidi, direction) */
```

```css
select[data-reset] {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<select data-reset>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
<select data-original>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

However, that will set the properties to their [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value). That initial value, defined in the spec, will probably differ from the default stylesheet used by browsers. So it won't work in practice.

Then, is there a way to restore the values from that user agent stylesheet? Not directly. However, you can just copy the styles from the default stylesheet.

```css
all: unset; /* Reset */
/* ... */   /* Default styles */
```

```css
select[data-reset] {
  /* Reset */
  all: unset;

  /* Default styles (on Firefox 41) */
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: -moz-combobox;
  border-color: threedface;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: -moz-comboboxtext;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font: ;
  line-height: normal !important;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  text-align: start;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

```html
<select data-reset>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
<select data-original>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

But there is still a problem: `select` elements are replaced elements, and therefore their representation is outside the scope of CSS. Then, by default, on Firefox `select`s appear a bit different than what the internal stylesheet says.

To get closer to the original appearance, you can use

```css
border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
font: initial;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 13.3333px;
```

So the full code would be

```css
all: unset;
-moz-appearance: menulist;
-moz-user-select: none;
background-color: -moz-combobox;
border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: -moz-comboboxtext;
cursor: default;
display: inline-block;
font: initial;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 13.3333px;
line-height: normal !important;
margin: 0;
overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
page-break-inside: avoid;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0;
text-shadow: none;
white-space: nowrap !important;
word-wrap: normal !important;
writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
```

```css
select[data-reset] {
  all: unset;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: -moz-combobox;
  border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: -moz-comboboxtext;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font: initial;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 13.3333px;
  line-height: normal !important;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  text-align: start;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

```html
<select data-reset>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
<select data-original>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and there's plenty of good info in there.  Unfortunately there is no actual solution offered here that does what I want, but you definitely deserve an upvote for the effort.  I'm beginning to wonder if what I'm asking for is actually impossible...

Comment: @billynoah I forgot to say that nope, once the default styles have been overriding, you can't get them back (without removing the overriding styles, and without assuming that the default styles are the initial ones). So you must use Firefox specific styles. However, you can prevent those from screwing other browsers by using [`@-moz-document`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3123063/1529630).