# How can I disable a whole CSS stylesheet on a specific list of domains?

Tags: css, css-selectors, userstyles

The browser I'm using, [qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/discussions/5733), allows me to set a CSS file that applies those styles to every web site (but doesn't allow you to set it per page/domain, as far as I can tell), so I downloaded a dark theme CSS stylesheet from [solarized-everything-css](https://github.com/alphapapa/solarized-everything-css/blob/master/css/solarized-dark/solarized-dark-all-sites.css), but it seems the result on some website is unsatisfactory.

Therefore, I'd like to know if CSS offers a way to *not* apply a sequence of rulesets (in my case it'd be the whole stylesheet) on some domains. Something long the lines of

```css
@this-web-site-is-NOT-in-the-black-list-in("list.txt") {
    /* the content of the dark theme CSS goes here*/
}
```

If it was possible, then I would add each problematic site to that sort of blacklist.

Comment: There's https://stackoverflow.com/q/3123063 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document, but neither are very compatible. If it were me, I'd run a bit of JS instead to check if the current site is compatible, and apply a root selector if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS itself cannot do this, because CSS is designed to apply only to a site from which it is loaded within the browser environment. Normally this happens by looking at resources listed in an HTML file's `<head>`, but can also happen from JavaScript injection via userscripts/addons/extensions a user has installed in their web browser.

So you need to use a 'user' style for this, which means you need to use a web browser that supports this. If the browser you're using (qutebrowser) does not allow you to set specific domains/URLs, then this will not be possible for you without creating your own user script (written in JavaScript, presumably) to apply this functionality on top of what the browser supports natively.