# CSS that firefox and not webkit can read

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

Is there a way to specify some CSS that firefox can read but webkit browsers cannot, or visa versa?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?  Rule number 1 of UI design is to not segregate users.....no matter what browser they insist on using.

Comment: not for segregation, there was a slight difference in visual rendering between Webkit and Firefox that I wanted to resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are not alone who wants this:

[Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

And you can view more tricks here:

http://stephenkui.com/code-css-only-to-firefox-ie-or-safari/

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to do that..

there is also a hack

> @-moz-document url-prefix() {
>
> ```
>   #my-id { font-size: 100%; }
>   }
> ```

This should target only firefox and not other browsers