# mozilla specific css

Tags: html, css, mozilla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

I need to target firefox specifically because of their `min-width` / `box-sizing` bug.

So I have 1 normal `min-width`, but for mozilla I want a different `min-width`.

Is there any pure CSS/HTML solution available?

Thanks

Comment: what `min-width` firefox problems? Create a http://JSfiddle.net

Comment: @MiG bug in question: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653643

Comment: From reading the linked-to bug report, it appears that this bug is triggered by using "-moz-box-sizing:border-box". Is there any way you could either stop using this property or switch the effected elements to "-moz-box-sizing:content-box" instead of using a hack ([not a best practice by any stretch of the imagination](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/keep_css_simple/))?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following to target (as far as I understand it) *all* versions of Firefox, and nothing else:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* firefox-only css goes here */
}
```