# CSS dynamic layout with mobile view versus normal view in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My problem is the following. I have a two column layout. But what I want do do is kind of complicated and I haven't found a good tutorial/question here on stackoverflow which handled my problem accurately.

I have the following image which represents my layout as it currently is.

**Current page layout**

[image: The current desktop layout]

On mobile view this is the desired result:

**Desired result**

[image: The desired result]

How to make sure that the first green block positions itself between the red and the purple block, but the second and third block positions itself underneath the purple block.

This is a problem because the second block is in an normal positioning beside the red block and locally ends up underneath the red block if I apply the solution of [Two column layout, fixed right column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532575/two-column-layout-fixed-right-column)

I have provided with a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdibbets/LgKP5/ that replicates the situation.

The HTML

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="yellow1">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="yellow2">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="black">
    <div id="green1">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="green2">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="green3">
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
    <div id="purple1">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="purple2">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="purple3">
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
span
    {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 50px 50px;
        font-size:4em;
        font-weight:800;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px gray;
        font-family:sans-serif;
    }

#red {
    background-color:red;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    display:inline-block;
}
#yellow1, #yellow2
    {
    background-color:yellow;
    border: 1px solid lightbrown;
    }
#black
    {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:gray;
    }
#green1, #green2, #green3
    {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lime;
    border:1px solid darkgreen;
    }
#blue
    {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid darkblue;
    background-color:lightblue;
    }
#purple1, #purple2, #purple3
    {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid darkpurple;
    background-color:purple;
    }
/* desktops and big resolution screens that can handle the normal layout */
@media only screen and (min-width: 875px) {
#red {
    width:600px;
}

#yellow1, #yellow2
    {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
    }
#black
    {
    float:right;
    }
#green1, #green2, #green3
    {
    clear:both;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    margin:20px;
    }
#blue
    {
    width:600px;
    }
#purple1, #purple2, #purple3
    {
    width:150px;
    margin:25px;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    }
}
/* small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 875px) {
#red {
    width:100%;
}
#yellow1, #yellow2
    {
    width:90%;
    margin:5%;
    float:left;
    }
#black
    {
    width:100%;
    }
#green1, #green2, #green3
    {
    width:90%;
    margin:5%;
    }
#blue
    {
    width:100%;
    }
#purple1, #purple2, #purple3
    {
   width:90%;
    margin:5%;
    }
}
```

It's no problem getting the "green blocks" as a whole into the dynamic mode.
But to "split" them is a whole different problem.

Is it possible to activate html code based on screen resolutions in the style of the IE conditional comments? That I can present a whole other set of HTML if screen resolution is...

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't match with your second picture

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm posting the question... That is my desired result.

Comment: The only way to do this would be with `Flexbox`.

Comment: Flexbox is interesting... but alas in the real world with everyday consumers, you have to deal with "old" standards... Will keep it in mind for when it might be mainstream in 2 or 3 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with my own answer by using my own written library:

A functional example is shown on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mdibbets/U3m4m/

If you need more explanation http://all-purpose-programming.blogspot.nl/2014/02/chaning-order-of-appearance-of-elements.html

```
/* Copyright 2014 Michael Dibbets, all rights reserved. 
    This library is free to use for non commercial use, 
    if you leave a comment below the blog post at 
    http://all-purpose-programming.blogspot.nl/2014/02/chaning-order-of-appearance-of-elements.html
    where you are implementing this libary.
    For commercial use contact me to come to an licensing agreement.
    mdibbets [at] outlook [dot] com
    My prices are fair and reasonable.
    ususage of this script without notification of the author 
    in the before mentioned ways is not permitted.
*/
function JX_responsive_sort(precursor)
    {
    if(typeof precursor == 'undefined')
        {
        precursor = 'conditional';
        }
    // our sorting array
    var orderofthings = new Array();
    // window width 
    var windowwidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    // get all classes named conditional
    jQuery('.'+precursor).each(function()
       {
       // get all classes of the conditional element
       var classList = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
       // loop through all classes of the current element
       // backwards compatible... of course
       for(c=0;c<classList.length;c++)
          {
          item=classList[c];
          // no need for this one bub
          if(item != precursor)
              {
              if(item.substring(0,11) == precursor)
                  {
                  // sanitise the item
                  item = item.substring(12,item.length);
                  // from which screenwidth is this rule active?
                  var startwidth = parseInt(item.substring(0,item.indexOf('_'))); 
                  // to which screenwidth is this rule active?
                  var endwidth = parseInt(item.substring(item.indexOf('_')+1,item.indexOf('_',item.indexOf('_')+1)));
                  if(windowwidth >= startwidth && windowwidth <= endwidth)
                      {
                      // remove the widths so all that remains are commands
                      item = item.substring(item.indexOf('_',item.indexOf('_')+1)+1,item.length);    
                      // split on hypens, since they are the commands separators
                      var commands = item.split(/-/);
                      for(i=0;i<commands.length;i++)
                          {
                          // get the instructions
                          var instructions = commands[i].split('_');
                          // to know the command remove the first element
                          var command = instructions.shift();
                          // command order - Instruction to display the elements in the desired order.
                          // This is a top level ordering of parent elements in the conditional_mainwrap 
                          // In order to change the ordering of child elements you'll have to "pop" them
                          // a level higher.
                          // allowed variables:
                          // 0 : order number priority. Try not to cause conflicts
                          if(command == 'order')
                              {
                              // add the this element at the desired position into the order of things.
                              orderofthings.push({order: instructions[0] , theobj : this });
                              }
                          // command pop - Instruction to remove the current element from its parent,
                          // and attach it to the parents parent.
                          if(command == 'pop')
                              {
                              // an item that switches positions needs an "returning" wrapper.
                              // that is the first parent.
                              // Then we have the normal container that needs to be escaped.
                              // Then we have parent where we wish to attach it to.
                              if(jQuery(this).parent().attr('id') == precursor + '_wrap_' + jQuery(this).attr('id'))
                                  {
                                  jQuery(this).appendTo($(this).parent().parent().parent());
                                  }
                              }
                          // command repop - Instruction to return the current element to it's designated position
                          // This is why a poppable element needs a wrapper, so we know where to return it.
                          if(command == 'repop')
                               {
                               jQuery(this).appendTo('#conditional_wrap_'+jQuery(this).attr('id'));
                               }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }              
          }
       });
    // set a simple variable to get the jQuery object of the parent wrap
    parentkeeper = jQuery('.'+precursor+'_mainwrap');
    // sort the arrays so the orderofthings get's it's sorting from the ORDER command.
    orderofthings = orderofthings.sort(keysrt('order',false));
    for(c=0;c<orderofthings.length;c++)
        {
        if(typeof orderofthings[c] != 'undefined')
            {
            jQuery(orderofthings[c]['theobj']).appendTo(parentkeeper);
            }
        }
    }
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
JX_responsive_sort();
});
jQuery( window ).resize(function() 
    {
    JX_responsive_sort();
    });
function keysrt(key,desc) {
  return function(a,b){
   return desc ? ~~(a[key] < b[key]) : ~~(a[key] > b[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can do it with

`position: absolute;`

and give exact

`height`

and

`top`

attributes of your elements. Can you check this one: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxncb/9/)

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for, it kind of defeats the purpose of a dynamic flow layout, especially since the height of the elements can't be predicted. a point for effort though.