# CSS Style with server side code - Classic ASP

Tags: css, asp-classic

I have a very old application that I'm working on and the style sheet has server code mixed in it.

For example:

```
.curCTRL { position:absolute; border:0px; background-color:<%=obj.htmlcolorconvert(obj.maskcolor) %>; <%if session("ISFF") then%>padding-right:1px;<%end if%> z-index:50; font-family: ms sans serif; font-size: 8pt;}
```

There are **many** lines just like this.  I know that back in the day you could do this and I guess it wasn't frowned upon...  I think style standards today are little tighter as I don't see too many style sheets like this anymore.  However, this application allows users to have unlimited colors and fonts (to their liking).  So the call to the COM object is necessary.

So my question is should I just stick with this format or is there a way I can clean it up and make this style sheet a true .css file rather than a style sheet inside a classic .asp file?

Any and all suggestions welcomed.

If the answer is to leave it for now...  Then fine, I'm OK with that suggestion.  However, when we update to a more modern tool set (i.e. ASP.Net), how would we set it up so that different users have custom colors and fonts?

**Would server controls be the best bet?**

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it.  We all shudder at old code, especially if its our own.  But hey, if people people use it, it must be worth something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just leave it, unless it's causing an actual problem.

Otherwise, a "modern" solution would be to use a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), particularly the [variables feature](http://lesscss.org/#-variables).

This part worries me:

```
<%if session("ISFF") then%>padding-right:1px;<%end if%>
```

That looks suspiciously like it's adding extra `padding-right` for only Firefox, which seems a bit of an odd thing to do.

If that really has to be done, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving it.  If the application is working fine then you should have no problem. The work involved is too much for very little outcome.