# Absolute positioning not displaying correctly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is it possible to have only one CSS property different in Chrome in comparison to Firefox?

A certain element has absolute positioning and is displaying correctly in Firefox but in Chrome it appears 2 pixels lower.

Comment: We need to see at least some code to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target just Firefox use this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
</style>

<h1>This should be red in FF</h1>
```

I got this answer from another stack overflow question:
[Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

You can test this by opening the following jsFiddle in both browsers: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/5xu9s/)

Comment: I'll try it and report back... Thanks!