# Firefox rendering issue with drupal zen theme and nice menu

Tags: css, drupal, firefox, cross-browser, suckerfish

I am building a site on Drupal usiong a custom theme based on the zen theme and using the nice menus module to generate a horizontal sons of suckerfish dropdown menu. My horizontal nice menus block works brilliantly in all browser (even in IE!) but seems to break in firefox, which is extremely unusual.

The second level menu should drop down directly below the top level menu item, which it does in all browsers except firefox (I am currently using 9.0.1). When I open the 2nd level menu in firefox, the 2nd level menu is displayed below the first (as it should), but left aligned to the left of it's parent menu, instead of being aligned below it's parent menu item. Any ideas?

Here is the url: http://www.crowstonstack.co.uk/new

Comment: If you have found a bug in a module, you should report it to the module's issue queue so it can be fixed.

Comment: It has been put on the issues for the module, but I'm not sure if this is an issue with my custom css.

Comment: It seems to work fine in FF 10. It didn't work in FF8, but an update skipped me right past FF9 and can no longer see the problem, but I would think it has something to do with the relative positioning of the secondary list

Answer (score 1):

change the value as per below in http://www.crowstonstack.co.uk/new/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus_default.css

This should fix it.

```
ul.nice-menu-down ul {
left: 57px;
}
```

This solution is only for firefox and might break the look in other browsers. So once you confirm its working you will need to put it as a condition. for  more on this go to

[Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Cheers,
Vishal