# Dropdown list disappear on Firefox

Tags: php, css, firefox

I have a problem with a dropdown list only on Firefox on Windows (working fine on FF on Mac), Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari.

When I click on the dropdown list and move the mouse to do my selection, the menu closes suddenly.

I can't select anything.

This is a part of my code.

CSS:

```css
.table {
   background:#ffffff;
}
.table ul {
   display: block;
   float:left;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:1px solid #C9C9C9;
}
.table ul.categ {
   width: 157px;
}
.table ul li {
   height:24px;
   list-style:none;
   padding:5px 10px;
}
.table ul li.title {
   font-weight:bold;
   background:#333;
   color:#fff;
}
.table ul li.even {
   background:#fff;
}
.table ul li.odd{
   background:#FFFFE6;
}
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<form>
    <div class="table">
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Titles</li>
            <li class="even">
                <select name="titles[]">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="title1">Title 1</option>
                    <option value="title2">Title 2</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GASsx/)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, here the part of my code with the fix. Hope it could help other people.

```
.table ul li.even {
    background:#fff; 
    position:relative; /* this fix the unclickable dropdown list */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `<` in front of your first option. Not sure if this would be causing your issue or not. Also, are you ending your `<form>` tag?

Comment: the closing `form` is not an issue for sure, but the missing `<` might be easily

Comment: Ops, sorry the < was copy/paste fault here.

The strange thing is that if I place the dropdown list out of my <ul><li class=even></li></ul>, it works, but it doesn't work inside that code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to Hack your CSS for FF on windows. There is an excellent post here on the topic [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)