# font-family: inherit; specific to mozilla firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have CSS to set my font-family to inherit like so:

```
font-family: inherit;
```

Is there a way to override this for Mozilla Firefox only? E.g. a specific attribute, like how I can write the following:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
```

which will be enabled/used on Mozilla browsers only?

Comment: @A.K I'm assuming he wants to know if there is an equivalent that is specific to firefox for font family, like how the radius property works. E.G. moz-font-family

Comment: @A.K. and Inkbug:i need a firefox specific attribute for font-family: inherit;

Answer (score 0):

There is no Firefox specific way to write `font-family: inherit;`. [Mozilla support inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/inherit) like any other browser, if that is what you mean?

Vendor-prefixed properties (like those used for some CSS3 properties) are only used for properties that are still "experimental" or evolving. The `inherit` keyword has been around for ages and therefor Firefox, like any other browser, implement it the way the CSS-specification states, without a vendor prefix.

If you want to target only Firefox with some specific CSS, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css) states that you can wrap the Mozilla specific properties with a [`@-moz-document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document) rule. As only Mozilla will recognize that as valid CSS, all other browsers will ignore it. A bit "hacky" perhaps, but it sounds like your best shot.

**Edit:**

To target only IE with specific CSS, one way is to put it in an IE-specific stylesheet file, and then use the conditional comments for IE. All browsers but IE will see this as an HTML-comment, and therefor ignore it, but IE will apply the styling in that file.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i need a firefox specific attribute for font-family: inherit; only.

Comment: @user1550884 Added some additional info on a workaround solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris. What would be the possible solution in case of IE?

Comment: @user1550884 Added some additional info on how to target IE with specific CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this to only target Firefox, the only problem is it's not in the CSS, I'm not sure if there is a way of doing this for font-family in the CSS.

```
<html>
...
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        font-family: inherit;
    }
    </style>
</head>
...
</html>
```