# How to specify a separate style for Firefox on Windows OS

Tags: css, windows, firefox

Am using a jQuery calendar on my website. When using the Windows Firefox browser, the calendar does not scroll from month to month. Is it possible to specify separate style for Windows Firefox?
I googled it a saw `-moz-windows-compositor` on many sites. What is the use of `-moz-windows-compositor` and how to use it?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Can they click through to the month even if the scroll doesn't work?

Comment: Which calendar are you referring to?

Comment: Why would `-moz-windows-compositor` be found "in many sites"? It seems to be intended only for use in the stylesheets used by Firefox and Thunderbird to customize their UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css) for targeting Firefox with CSS. Which calendar are you using? If the calendar doesn't scroll in Firefox, I don't think targeting it with CSS will help you much.

Comment: calender is scrolling but not showing the dates.. When i inspect it in mozilla it has dates, so i think it is not showing because of css pblms

Comment: Post a link or a fiddle if you can. That will help.