# What is the most practical way to check for "@supports" support using only CSS?

Tags: css

Following Eric Bidelman's Google I/O [presentation](http://www.moreawesomeweb.com/#1) yesterday, which touched on the subject of `@supports`, I figured I'd start playing with it in Chrome Canary. However, it's raised the obvious question:

What is the best way to check whether a browser supports `@supports` using only CSS?

---

I'm currently toying with it by simply checking whether `display: block` is supported. This method works, obviously, but I'm not sure if this is the most practical approach:

```
body { background:#fff; font-family:Arial; }
body:after { content:'Ek! Your browser does not support @supports'; }

@supports (display:block) {
    body { background:#5ae; }
    body:after { color:#fff; content:'Your browser supports @supports, yay!'; }
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNGU2/) demo of this in action.

These attempts do *not* work (in Chrome Canary, at least):

```
@supports (@supports) { ... }
@supports () { ... }
@supports { ... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@supports` currently only tests property/value combinations, and nothing else. Your other options don't work because none of them are valid (including the last one with just the at-keyword followed by the opening brace!). The property/value pair requirement is dictated by the grammar for `@supports`, which you can find in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports).

Simply test for a property/value pair that you know is guaranteed to work across all user agents whether or not `@supports` is implemented. This (sort of) eliminates the possibility that you'll run into a user agent that implements `@supports` but not that property/value combination, focusing on its support for `@supports` instead.

Your given example of `display: block` will suffice. Your use of the cascade to check if a browser *does not* implement `@supports` by overriding declarations within a `@supports` rule for browsers that *do* support it is also acceptable (being the only obvious way to do it anyway).

Comment: Could there be a situation where `display: block` *isn't* included in a CSS implementation? If so, would it be more logical to test against something which would never be part of CSS; something like `@supports not (_:_) {}`?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly `@supports not (_:_) {} == @supports not (whateverbutthisdoesntmakeanysenseproprty:5px) {}` so if the property value pair is invalid or property is not valid at all, browser will just assume that it is not yet supported

Comment: @James Donnelly: Practically speaking, no - I'd rather worry about a browser implementing `@supports` incorrectly. But if you want, you can do that as well.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Yes. Of course, you do have to make sure that it doesn't break the `@supports` rule.

Comment: @BoltClock yap, if the `prop:val` is valid, it won't break..BTW it also checks the valid units for the value, I don't know whether that's case sensitive or not.. like `px != PX`, am sure it won't be...

Comment: Man I need to earn a 3 digit rep with a K to get my answers to be selected as correct ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien well, (sometimes - sadly) answers are accepted from the OP. This does not necessarily say something about correctness, usefulness or comprehensiveness of the chosen answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien your answer is a good reference, but the question asks how to detect `@supports` within a browser, not how to *use* `@supports` within a supported browser.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Did you even read it? :) Read 2nd line in 2nd para

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did read it. You're explaining how `@supports` works (and why my failed tests didn't work), but you're not explaining whether or not that is a practical way to determine `@supports` support. I upvoted your answer because it's a good `@supports` reference. I didn't accept answer because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly `your example is completely fine here` Anyways it's k, I don't want any war here ;)

Answer (score 2):

David walsh blog has a nice tutorial about @supports [Link](http://davidwalsh.name/css-supports).

Indeed you JsFiddle work perfectly in Chrome Canary.

Valid syntax for @supports are,

```
@supports(prop:value) {
    /* more styles */
}

/* Negation */
@supports not(prop:value) {
    /* more styles */
}

/* `or` keyword*/
@supports(prop:value) or
         (prop:value){
    /* more styles */
}

/* `and` keyword*/
@supports(prop:value) and
         (prop:value){
    /* more styles */
}

/* `or`, `and` keywords*/
@supports(prop:value) or
         (prop:value) and 
          (prop:value) {
    /* more styles */
}
```

Comment: His question was how to check whether `@supports` is **supported** using CSS only and not that how to check which property is supported :)

Comment: yup, figured it out lately

Comment: @NobalMohan is possible to check pseudo ? like @support `@supports .element(:focus-within) {` ?

Answer (score 2):

This will probably won't work, you cannot check whether `@supports` is supported or not by CSS only, your example is completely fine here, but there's no option for a straight approach here, for example you are using this :

```
@supports (@supports) {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Now that won't actually work, may be for [**Chrome Canary**](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html), this is fine `@supports` but when it goes ahead to check between parenthesis, it fails, why? It expects a CSS `property: value` pair inside the parenthesis and not any `@` rule, it actually checks whether any property is valid or not, even if you replace that with `@supports (@font-face)` won't work, further down, I'll explain you with a demo

When you use `@supports`, it comes with a keyword called `not` to check whether a specific style is supported by the browser or not, if yes, than apply, else apply other...

Example

```
@supports (-webkit-border-radius: 6px) {
    div:nth-of-type(1) {
        color: red;
    }
}

@supports not (-moz-border-radius: 6px) {
    div:nth-of-type(2) {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJBMP/) (Note : This works only on chrome canary as of now)

Explanation :

`@supports (-webkit-border-radius: 6px)` will check in Chrome Canary that whether a property called `-webkit-border-radius` is supported, if yes than go ahead, change the color of first `div` to `red` and it does, cuz Chrome Canary does support `-webkit` properties while the second will fail as Chrome doesn't support `-moz` prefixed properties, it will paint blue because I am using `not` here

```
@supports not (-moz-border-radius: 6px)
        ---^---
```

Hopefully FAQ

1) Why none of the styles are applied in browser?

That's because your browser doesn't support `@supports` yet and hence none will apply as browser will just ignore `@supports` rules

---

From the [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports)

> The ‘@supports’ rule is a conditional group rule whose condition tests
>   whether the user agent supports CSS property:value pairs

Comment: The demo doesn't actually explain why `@supports (@font-face)` doesn't work... it just explains how to *use* `@supports`, which as mentioned by the OP is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @BoltClock `@supports but when it goes ahead to check between parenthesis, it fails, why? It expects a CSS property: value pair inside the parenthesis and not any @ rule, it actually checks whether any property is valid or not, even if you replace that with @supports (@font-face) won't work` How can I provide him with the demo when @supports only work with property value pair?

Comment: You're demonstrating the difference between `@supports` and `@supports not` - what does that have to do with `@supports (@font-face)`? Although I guess that is answered by the FAQ bit, but your answer seems pretty confusing.

Comment: @BoltClock I shown him the demo that how it only works with properties and not `@` rules, further down I explained him how to work with `@supports` having a valid parameter of `property:value` combination, certainly `@font-face` has nothing to do with the demo as it JUST DON'T WORK, so I explained him how it works in the real way so he can't check the way he was trying to, as specified in his question `These attempts do not work (in Chrome Canary, at least):
@supports (@supports) { ... }` the intention was to clear how it works and I created a demo to show that

Comment: @BoltClock I guess this is what makes you confused hehe `I'll explain you with a demo`