# Feature detection for @supports?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, browser-feature-detection

How can I detect if a browser supports the CSS @supports feature? Since Internet Explorer and Safari don't support it, my web app doesn't know which styles to apply in those browsers.

Comment: What about Modernizer?

Comment: That's a framework, correct? If possible I'd like to stay away from frameworks as much as possible.

Comment: Nope...Feature detection JS - http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure CSS, you can sort of rely on the cascade to determine whether a browser understands `@supports` by making a `@supports` rule with a universally-supported declaration, such as a `color` declaration, and overriding another such rule that is declared globally:

```
#test {
    color: red;
}

@supports (color: green) {
    #test {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

[In *any* browser that implements `@supports` correctly, `#test` should have green text. Otherwise, it'll have red text.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/VWk93)

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584228/what-is-the-most-practical-way-to-check-for-supports-support-using-only-css) for a detailed explanation of the pure CSS method.

If you're looking to detect it using JavaScript, you can use the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) feature detection library as mentioned in the comments (be sure to include css-supports in your download config):

```
if (Modernizr.supports) {
    console.log('Your browser supports @supports.');
} else {
    console.log('Your browser does not support @supports.');
}
```

Comment: The pure CSS solution may be the answer I was looking for. Currently using something similar but was unaware of the overriding functionality.

Comment: Using your pure CSS solution, the base style rules are applied, even in browsers that previously displayed the style rules in a @supports block. EDIT: Does it matter if the supports block is within an media  block?

Comment: @Elitis: It should not matter - in that case the `@supports` block should apply if and only if the `@media` block also does. If you need to exclude the base styles from unsupporting browsers, move them to the `@supports` block instead. On the other hand, if you need to exclude the base styles from *supporting* browsers, you will have to override those too - that's the disadvantage of relying on overriding.