# Is there Firefox legacy-specific CSS that doesn't apply to Firefox Quantum?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-quantum

I have some CSS that uses some browser specific CSS. For Firefox I use:

`@-moz-document`

in front of my selector so only Firefox will use the CSS. However, the new Firefox Quantum is also using that CSS even though it renders CSS differently than Firefox due to it having a ["new CSS engine"](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2017/11/14/introducing-firefox-quantum/).

The new CSS engine actually makes it much closer to how Chrome renders my specific CSS, so even if there isn't a selector just for Firefox Quantum, if there was some way to have it ignore some selectors, that would work.

So I need a way to have some CSS only for Firefox (not Quantum) and ideally a way to have separate CSS only for Firefox Quantum.

Comment: @Rob: Think I should move my answer over to [that question you answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575563/conditional-css-rule-targeting-firefox-quantum)? (Yes, I plan to add a "use feature detection" prelude.)

Comment: @BoltClock I forgot about that one. It might be helpful but that makes this question a duplicate?

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, these are duplicates without a doubt. I'll merge my answer over later.