# Targeting browsers that don't support CSS grid with feature queries

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid, browser-feature-detection

**How can I reliable create a fallback for CSS grid styling for browsers that don't support the current spec, with a feature query or media query?**

According to articles like [this one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/css-grid-supporting-browsers-without-grid/), browsers ignore CSS that they can't parse. Therefore, I expected negative feature queries to work even on browsers that don't support it. E.g. IE11 does not support feature queries, so I expected it to ignore this line and apply the styles inside the query: `@supports not (display: grid){}`. However, as you can see in this test, [IE11 ignores all the styles inside that query](https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/EQGOmW).

I found a media query for IE10+, but that one excludes other browsers that don't support grid. Of course I could first declare the fallback styles and override them with a `@supports (grid-area: area)` query, but I prefer a solution that does not require overrides.

Comment: That requires overriding the fallback styling. Which means more lines of CSS and it’s harder to maintain: any change to the fallback design possibly needs an override too.

Comment: You should use @supports not (display:grid){}

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/browser-compatibility-css-grid-layouts-simple-sass-mixins/

Comment: @Gerard, yes of course. I tried both, neither worked. I updated my question with the more obvious way you suggested.

Comment: This may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33359157/3597276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> According to articles like this one, browsers ignore CSS that they can't parse [...] However, as you can see in this test, IE11 ignores all the styles inside that query.

Well, yeah. Since Internet Explorer doesn't understand feature queries *themselves*, it's going to ignore `@supports not (display: grid)` and everything inside it, because it doesn't understand what that means. Just like the article says.

[Overriding, i.e. making use of the cascade, is your only option.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584228/what-is-the-most-practical-way-to-check-for-supports-support-using-only-css/16585200#16585200) There is no clean way of doing this. The reality is that `@supports` was introduced too late to be useful for distinguishing browsers that don't support features that precede it, such as grid layout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I will look into feature detection with JS in order to avoid the cascading overrides.