# Is there a way to target specific css for firefox for android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, css, firefox, mobile

Is there a way to target specific `css` for `Firefox` for `android` and `ios`?

http://www.eventhuse.com/stag-weekends/stag-destinations/budapest/

```
<p style=" text-align: justify;">One of the more established stag do destinations for an experiential weekend, Budapest has its very own character. Indeed, in recent years, Budapest has taken on the role of the region’s party town. The food and wine are excellent and well priced, while there is only one word to describe the nightlife and that is ‘hot’. The city of Budapest with the Buda Hills to the west and the start of the Great Plain to the east, is not one that lags behind for a stag weekend as it offers everything and anything. From city tours and adrenaline pumped activities to sexy extras, there is a reason why this is one of Europe’s party capitals.</p>
```

that paragraph in the middle in chrome and opera seems fine... in my `galaxy s3` but in `firefox` the letters are bigger!

this is how i control it

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
    #page #main  #primary  #content article.page .entry-content p{ font-size:0.6em !important;}
    #page #main #primary #content-single  .fullpage-general-post .entry {font-size:0.6em  !important;}
    #page #main #primary #content-single  .fullpage-general-post .entry p{font-size:0.6em  !important;}
    #main #primary #content .entry ul li{font-size:0.6em  !important;}  
}
```

Any ideas how to target specifically `Firefox` on smartphones ?

Comment: Is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css) what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes i tried this code but i need only for android or ios, this code works for all firefox and my desktop version is fine

Comment: Have you tried to insert this code within the `@media only screen...` block?

Comment: Yes i tried to do that i even downloaded some plugin for android firexo to clear cache. Nothing happen :(

Comment: @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and max-device-width : 480px) {#page #main  #primary  #content article.page .entry-content p{ font-size:0.6em !important;} #page #main #primary #content-single  .fullpage-general-post .entry {font-size:0.6em  !important;}#page #main #primary #content-single  .fullpage-general-post .entry p{font-size:0.6em  !important;}#main #primary #content .entry ul li{font-size:0.6em  !important;}