# Firefox displays button's padding incorrect

Tags: css, firefox

Currently I'm creating a website and I have a little problem: only in Firefox button looks like this:
[image]

Although, in the rest browsers button looks like this
[image]

You can watch it here http://router.kg/ubiquiti
And another mistake I've noticed: every browser show button's padding like this

```
padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
```

Firefox shows only this:

```
padding: 10px 20px 15px;
```

Firefox v26.0

So, can anyone tell me where is the problem hiding?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write a css that specifically targets Firefox (in addition to the css that works on other browsers).

Check out how to do so here: [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

you should remove height and use only padding to size height of button .

```
input.button {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width:10em;
  padding:0.5em;
  text-align:left;
  background:green;
  border-radius:0.5em;
  color:white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Chvej

in your code you set height at 32px, wich doesn't allow button to grow over these 32px (different bomodel used by FF ?) but padding is still applied in FF