# Float for Mozilla only

Tags: css

I need to define float:none!important; for mozilla only, because in another browsers I need float:left. 
It's there a manner to define float for mozilla only? Standard solution with -moz-float... prefix doesn't works

Comment: follow this solution on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css

Answer (score 1):

use this and put your mozilla css only inside this 
it should be only affect mozilla browser

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    #my-id { font-size: 100%; }

}
```

[This website](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/#Safari) has more options as well

You can place this in your CSS file or between your `<style type='text/css'>` tags in your HTML. Works Fine!

Answer (score 0):

That begin with prefix

> "-moz". Prefix "-moz"

combined **with -document url-prefix()** is used in particular when creating additions to Firefox.

```
/* Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
  #your-id { float: left; }
}
```

[CSS hacks for Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer](http://basicuse.net/articles/pl/textile/html_css/css_hacks_for_mozilla_firefox_opera_safari_and_internet_explorer)