# css media query that targets firefox pc only

Tags: css, html

I want to add a specific style to my page but only on firefox running on a pc. I use this code to target just mac but what would be the windows equivalent? and Is there a way to do it with just media querys not javascript?

```
var FF = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);

if(FF) {
    if(navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac')>=0)
         {
            // is a mac and on firefox
         }
```

Comment: What style do you want to add?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Comment: Id like to hid a video tag but only on firefox-pc, it runs slow on pc but on my mac it plays fine.

Comment: Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css

Comment: You could ask a question about why your video runs slow in Firefox on PC :)

Comment: @misterManSam do you know why thou? lol if you go to http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/ you will notice that this plugin works fine on everything but firfox pc, any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Css hack for firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .cssSelector {
     font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

**[Reference](http://code-tricks.com/target-only-firefox-browser-with-css-hacks/)**

Comment: is this for mac and pc?

Answer (score 1):

[MDN Mozilla CSS Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) you can read all possible CSS extensions for mozilla also you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)