# firefox hide labels so they dont appear on firefox only

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Hi i was wondering is there any code which i can apply on a class which will make it not show on Firefox only? As i know there is a big for FF which doesn't let you hide the drop-down bars.. so i want to do a

`z-index:-1`;

on my labels which surround it.. but only want this to apply to Firefox nothing else? I can not find any ways on Google.. i just need some code which could do this for me?

```
label:before {
    content: '';
    right: 10px;
    top: 17px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    background: url(arrow.png);
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    z-index:-1;//this needs to only apply to firefox  
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Comment: Do you use any serverside technology? If so I would suggest to determine the browser agent serverside and create a separate stylesheet for each supported browser.

Comment: Thanks top link worked :)