# I want to ignore a CSS rule on Firefox

Tags: macos, css, firefox

I have the following feature in my current CSS:

```
.image {
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

However, it has a bizarre bug in Firefox OSX. I want to ignore it in this browser, but I want to keep it on everyone else. 
It is possible? Through css hacks, maybe?

Comment: [CSS Hacks Targeting Firefox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/). [Targeting firefox only with CSS](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/targeting-firefox-only-with-css). [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css). I trust you know how to use Google...

Comment: Could you please post an image of what's happening? I think that would make this question more useful to others. You won't be able to upload the image here but if you can upload it elsewhere I will edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line should fix your problem :)

```
.image {
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    -moz-appearance-mix-blend-mode: none; // HERE
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, didnt solve that weird bug. But, with your idea, i discovered something interesting:

if i put this line:

border:1px solid transparent;

Voilá. Its fixed! O.o