# Loading SVG filter in sandboxed iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, cross-domain

I am trying to load an SVG to use as a CSS filter as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter. I am hosting the SVG on my root domain of the application and I am using the said SVG inside an iframe that I create using the srcdoc attribute. The html that the iframe loads is stored as a string inside my main application. The reason I use the iframe is because I render arbitrary user input in that iframe and I have set the sandbox attribute ( no cross origin requests and no access to root application cookies ). I am receiving the following error:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL http://localhost:3000/filter.svg from frame with URL about:srcdoc. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I attempted to use the URL.createObjectURL function and pass the svg directly but I still receive the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/692e5c8b-f87e-49cd-9efd-68ee65e98ea6.svg
```

I even attempted to load an html file hosted on the same domain as the iframe and I still receive the error that it's unable to load URL localhost/filter.svg from localhost. I guess that's correct since the sandbox does not give same-origin access.
My question is how can I achieve the filter effect without removing the same-origin sandboxing? I cannot understand why using url() property of css is considered a dangerous cross-origin request but loading an image with the `<img>` tag is allowed...

Similar issue with no answer:
[XMLNS W3 URL for SVG spec now throwing error in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646388/xmlns-w3-url-for-svg-spec-now-throwing-error-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by inlining the svg to the html of the iframe. Relative issue that in the end helped me with the fix: [SVG filter not showing up in Firefox, working fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676342/svg-filter-not-showing-up-in-firefox-working-fine-in-chrome)