# Firefox Print too small

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, scale

we have a kind of "note-function" on our portal and when I try to print this site, it's size is fine on Chrome and Internet-Explorer, but will be too small on Firefox. When i set the scale to 90% in Firefox, it looks like the Chrome/IE Version.

I tried to manipulate the body with `scale()` per media print, but than it looks strange...

Is there a way to manipulate the Firefox printing-option scale per css/js? Or does anyone else had this problem before? :/

I am pretty sure our customer won't listen when I tell him "Yeah just let the users change their printing options" :D

Here some Screenshots to explain what i mean:

[image: The bad looking one on Firefox]

How it should look, and looks in Chrome and IE without problems

[image: Firefox with Scale 90%]

Answer (score 0):

I would try overriding your CSS when using firefox like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
       color: red;
       }
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>This should be red in FF</h1>

 </body>
</html>
```

See Here [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: the problem is, i am not sure WHAT to override :D i already tried to set max-width's for the table, the comment-box, the box containing the icons, etc. hoping it may be something to wide that confuses only firefox. But nothing seems to help. 
When i use `transform: scale(0.9)` for firefox only on the wrapper-div, it just looks stupid and still get's shown to small. 
Maybe it's not a width-problem but a firefox-problem :/

Comment: @binaryKitten If its not a page width problem then it might not be something you can fix by changing your code. That being said I did find this thread that might relate to your problem: [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/958617)

Comment: yeah, thank you. i have a similar feeling :/ it seems like ticket close - won't fix....