# Is there a way to change the relative position value of an element by browser?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, position

I have a quick question, I'm wondering if it is possible to change the position value of a certain element in ONLY FireFox by adjusting the main CSS file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Define Firefox. Is Palemoon Firefox? Is my own build compiled from unmodified source Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`@-moz-document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions) to only target Firefox. Add it to your main.css to overwrite the existing rules.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    element {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to use your code to target an id and it's not working. this is my code 
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#buttons-container {
        position: relative;
        top:206px;
    }
}

Comment: Nevermind, got it. thanks alot.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.