# how to apply css value for specific IE version

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a class in name of "myclass". In IE8, i need to apply the z-index as 5 for the "myclass" So i have tried to acheive it by using following methods.

```
.myclass{
z-index: 5\9  
}
```

---> It applies from IE10 onwards not only in IE8

```
.myclass{
z-index: 5 \0/ 
}
```

----> this also applies from IE10 onwards not only in IE8 and                   it create syntax error

How to acheive it only in IE8?

Comment: https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css+ie+8+hacks&*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use targeting.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

Also, it appears as if a question similar to this has been asked before, [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)
may be useful to you.

Comment: Hi Boo,

I have a "myclass" property in separate css file.For he single property issue , referring the another file is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include a seperate CSS file by using a conditional comment to overwrite your css rule specifically in IE8. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/path/to/main-styles.css" />

<!-- The following lines will only be interpreted by IE version 8 or lower -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/path/to/ie8-overwrites.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: For single property , adding the new file is not feasible.

Comment: When optimizing for IE8 a property is most unlikely to remain single ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving z-index with position relative or absolute. z-index might not work with static element.
Try:

```
    .myclass{
        position:relative;
        z-index:5;
    }
```