# how to set div width specific for mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

I am using css to set width of a div in HTML. I need to set a specific width for mozilla. I am able to find the margin tag specific for mozilla but not able to get the width tag. Below is the code:

```
     .box2 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc( 100% - 211px);
        margin-left: 208px;
        -webkit-logical-width: calc(100% - 117px);
        -webkit-margin-start: 115px;
        **MOZILLA SPECIFIC WIDTH: calc(100% - 117px);**
        -moz-margin-start: 115px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 33px;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's possible.   Example:

```
   @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .box2  {
            width: 100px;
        }
    }
```

There as a lot on mozilla CSS extensions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions