# Target everything except Firefox using CSS

Tags: css, firefox

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953491/667903) says we can target Firefox using the following CSS:

```css
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
      h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <h1>This should be red in FF</h1>
```

I want to apply a CSS rule to all browsers except gecko/Firefox, as the CSS rule doesn't display properly in Firefox.

How do I use CSS to target everything except Firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: ``@-moz-document url-prefix()`` only works for FF. You should use it too set values to fix what is not styling correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to use `not` @GerardoBLANCO?

Comment: not for this case. Why dont you post another question with your style problem and I can help you

Comment: OK, thank you @GerardoBLANCO, it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264482/limit-number-of-lines-of-text-in-firefox)