# How to detect if a user is using IE and inform them that the site doesn't support IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm creating a website with Zepto, so it doesn't support any Internet Explorer version.

How can I detect if a user is using Internet Explorer and redirect them to a page informing that the website doesn't support IE?

I've read about conditional comments, but them aren't supported in Internet Explorer 10.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, Zepto appears to have an [IE10 branch](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/tree/ie10) now.

Comment: I didn't know that, so now it supports IE10?

Comment: Not yet, but it might in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can never know for sure, but an easy option is to look at the user-agent (in e.g. PHP).

Also take a look here: [How to display browser specific HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738831/how-to-display-browser-specific-html)

Answer (score 0):

Setup the document like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

For IE10 use this:

```
    if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()
){    
document.documentElement.className+=' ie10'; 
}
```

Then, what you do with these classes depends on whether you want to just show/hide a div with css, or use javascript to redirect the page.

Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    // Detecting IE
    var IE;
    if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8, .ie9, .ie10')) {
        IE = true;
    }

    if (IE) {
        // redirect
       window.location.replace('http://www.myotherpage.com');
    } 

}(jQuery));
```

OR CSS:

```
.ie6 .myDivClassName,
.ie7 .myDivClassName,
.ie8 .myDivClassName,
.ie9 .myDivClassName,
.ie10 .myDivClassName {
  display: block; 
}
```

Depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the IE10?

Comment: Sorry was in the middle of editing my answer when I re-read your question...IE10 you can find by using a javascript snippet, see above.

Comment: Thanks, but how I display another page to inform the users that the website doesn't support IE?

Comment: window.location.replace to redirect to another page, or just have div that displays a message for IE only. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript

Comment: To IE9 and inferior I use something like this: <!--[if lt IE  ]> <div>This website doesn't support Internet Explorer...</div> <![endif]-->. But where I put this div in the function that you suggest to IE10?

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use the CSS way because I'm using Zepto instead o jQuery. I put the  if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()
){    
document.documentElement.className+=' ie10'; 
} inside a script tag before the head?

Comment: Inside a script tag inside the head. Or in a separate .js file, your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt. Where in your example do you have the myDivClassName, because I only see that in the css

Comment: myDivClassName is the the class name of the div you happen to want to show for IE, but hide for other browsers.

Comment: Something like this? <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"><div class="myDivClassName"></div> <![endif]-->

Comment: That div is not in a head tag or a body tag. It needs to be in a body tag.

Comment: Ok, so I put that div in the body tag, and I style the div with a "display:none", in order to hide the div when the browser isn't IE, right?