# CSS grid-auto-flow in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am trying to make following example work in IE 11:
https://dojo.telerik.com/ariSElEj

Looks like this in normal browsers: 
[image]

My CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 100px);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 33.3333%;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
```

IE 11 just ignores the CSS and displays 1 column.

Is there anyway to have this layout in IE with minimal change to the CSS? OR, does anyone suggest "browser specific HTML" like this example -> **[How to display browser specific HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738831/how-to-display-browser-specific-html)**

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Grid Layout not working in Edge and IE 11 even with -ms prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-edge-and-ie-11-even-with-ms-prefix)