# How to access a particular browser in JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a legacy application which works only in IE. Now if the user access the application from other browser I have to show a button or link , on click which redirect the request to IE. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: @statosdotcom: Browser detection can't solve this. Browser _redirection_ is not a thing: clientside JavaScript can't launch executables. The closest thing to this is something like IE Tab Chrome Extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch IE from a link in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome)

Comment: @Amadan, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible to open another browser from current browser.

You could instead display message over your site and let the user know about it

> [How to display browser specific HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738831/how-to-display-browser-specific-html)

Edit: I am assuming you don't have control on user's platform.

Comment: I don't have access to user platform.

Comment: what you are asking is not possible but consider displaying a message about incompatibility on your webpage. For example, look at what happens when you don't login to quora or linkedin, it just shows a pop-up window and rest of the site is inaccessible. This is the simplest way to do it from front-end.

Comment: Yes. Seems no other option. My plan was to show the message and then provide a  link or button to navigate to another browser. Thanks